# Duplicate Key Error in phpAdmin

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I am using PHPAdmin to create a unique index on a field. It comes back with Error 1062 - Duplicate Key on . . . then it gives me the offending data. The issue is the data is NOT a duplicate. Each record has a unique entry in that field. Thinking it was an anomaly, I deleted that entry and tried again. It gave me the same error this time on the last row before the deleted record.

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE prospects ( 
   client_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   company varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
   created_on timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   ... some other fields like first_name...
  PRIMARY KEY (client_id),
  KEY first_name (first_name,last_name) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1958 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Alter table statement failing:

```
ALTER TABLE acceler6_accelrefer.prospects ADD UNIQUE company_ui (company);
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the table CREATE schema and the actual insert statement PHPMyADMin is creating that generates the error to your post and we'll be able to determine the issue.  You can run `show create table yourtablename;` to get create statement.

Comment: Probably your data IS a duplicate. Always assume that it is you who is wrong before blaming it on a product.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Here's the Create Table

CREATE TABLE `prospects` (
 `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`),
 KEY `first_name` (`first_name`,`last_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1958 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Here is the SQL that tries to create the index.
ALTER TABLE `acceler6_accelrefer`.`prospects` ADD UNIQUE `company_ui` (`company`);

Comment: Hey Shadow, as a programmer I'm well aware of that concept thanks, but there are no duplicates in the table.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I trust mysql more. Anyhow, without seeing the actual data, it is impossible to tell what may have gone wrong. Test the company field and list the duplicate values.

Comment: @GabeO I put a query in my answer below you can use to prove there's no duplicates, run it and see.

Answer (score 0):

As much as you don't want to hear it again from the comments, you've got a duplicate `company` name.   Note, this does not mean the entire record is a duplicate, but when you add a unique on company, every record has to have a unique `company`.  I'm going to guess you've sometimes got more than one prospect entry per company.

To verify, try this:

```
 SELECT count(company), count(distinct company) FROM prospects;
```

If these number are identical, then ok, you win, you've not got more than one record with the same company, but I'm certain they'll be different.

To find out exactly which ones are duplications you can do this:

```
 SELECT company, count(company) AS counter 
  FROM prospects 
    GROUP BY company
  HAVING counter > 1;
```

If you just want fast lookup of the `client_id`'s by company, drop the `UNIQUE` and just use a regular key.

```
 ALTER TABLE acceler6_accelrefer.prospects ADD KEY company_ui (company);
```